# Sanitizing insert with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this snippet where I'm trying to insert large set of data to MySQL database.

```
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $sql = "INSERT into universe (`zone`, `area`, `sub`) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]')";
}
```

I tried 'preparing' the data prior to the insert and made an attempt to sanitize,

```
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $sql = $conn->prepare ("INSERT into universe (`zone`, `area`, `sub`) values(?,?,?)");
    $sql = bind_param("sss", '$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]');
}
```

And this gives me an error :

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bind_param()

Where and how do you suggest that I define **bind_param** earlier? Thank you.

Comment: It's a method of [`mysql_stmt`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) not a function - `mysqli` returns an instance of `mysqli_stmt` - see more here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: You can move the prepare to outside the loop, prepare once and execute in each loop (you don't seem to have the execute though)

Comment: To increase insert speed significant than use a transaction and commit every few hundred rows. Currently you at committing for each row which is a quite a large overhead.

Comment: Can the down voter add a comment?

Comment: @RyanVincent yes I think so too. Thanks for pointing out. Presume what Nigel Ren suggest would help me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't far from the expected result.

[bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is a method from the [mysqli_stmt](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) class. You get an instance of this class when doing `$sql = $conn->prepare(...);`

All you have to do is to call that function from the `$sql` object.

By the way, you don't have to wrap `$emapData[x]` into single quotes.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT into universe (`zone`, `area`, `sub`) values(?, ?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param("sss", $emapData[0], $emapData[1], $emapData[2]);
```

Comment: Thank @Cid. This helps :)